# Does anyone know how to access this function: GenerateNewWindowLightbox("Viewer.aspx?documentID=" + 21, null, true, "");

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the plugin below, the documentation says I should be able to call GenerateNewWindowLightbox  as a global function - but when I try it says undefined.  The documentation is in German - but I have feeling it has something to do with scope and maybe a smarter javascript person than I might know how to get quick and easy access to the GenerateNewWindowLightbox function in the plugin below:

[Windows Aero Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/synergyrms/source/browse/branches/SourceCode/SynergyRMS/Scripts/jquery-AeroWindow.js?spec=svn301&r=301)

Comment: In the script, the function is clearly not global.  It's running within the scope of a function that gets called by `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not in global scope.For bringing to global scope, use

```
window.GenerateNewWindowLightbox = function(NewWindowURL, WindowTitle, ShowDesktopIcon,e)
```

instead of

```
function GenerateNewWindowLightbox(NewWindowURL, WindowTitle, ShowDesktopIcon, e)
```

Comment: Is there a way to call it without modifying the plugin?  I tried the above method and the plugin functionality seems to break

Comment: @WarrenJThompson - You'd have to modify the plugin, it's just not designed to allow you to access that function from outside that scope.  You could try adding at line 1101: `window.gnwlb = GenerateNewWindowLightbox;` and then calling `gnwlb();` from the global scope.

Comment: The `window.GenerateNewWindowLightbox` function can be called from anywhere ,I do not think,the plugin could be broken for this reason. Please check

Comment: Ok - I guess this is the best that can be done - it creates an artifact - but I'm manually removing it via $.remove()

Comment: @WarrenJThompson - If the plugin is open source, maybe you can improve it and submit a patch..